# Hovering child element of an even element using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I need to set hover of 'a' element that is a child of 'tr', which is picked by nth-child(even) selector.

Basically I've got the normal table with multiple rows, and inside every table cell there is an 'a' link, that I want to highlight while hovered, but **only** in the even rows.

My CSS code:

```
.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td a:hover {
    color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

And it's not working.

How can I solve this?

```css
.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td a:hover {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text here</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click here</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your CSS seems to work fine.. Check the Snippet which I added.

Answer (score 1):

The css you are using is working perfectly:

```css
.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td a:hover {
    color: #3c3c3c;
    color:red;/*for dislay i have use this red color;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
.table-striped tr:nth-child(even):hover td a {
  color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

Comment: This will change the color of `a` when hovered anywhere on the row.